How to insert new row Mariadb perl
My host moved to MariaDB from mySQL. This is a Perl CGI.pm script. If I use use DBI; and use DBD::MariaDB;, most everything translates well to the new database. But when I try to insert a new row it wants data for each column. I get:

Software error: DBD::MariaDB::st execute failed: Incorrect integer value: '' for column `mydb`.`mytable`.`mycolumn` at row 1 at myscript.cgi line 18302.

my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:MariaDB:database=$database;host=localhost", $MYSQLuserid, $MYSQLpassword, { RaiseError => 1, PrintError => 0 });
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO mytable ($placeholders) values ($questionmarks)");
$sth->execute(@new_row) or die "Failed to execute statement: " . $sth->errstr;
$new_order_number = $sth->{LAST_INSERT_ID};
$sth->finish() or die $DBI::errstr;
$dbh->disconnect()  or die $DBI::errstr;

I've tried modifying NULL to: NOT NULL, NULL/none/as defined and NULL.
This was never an issue with mysql and I need to be able to leave columns empty for future use.
Tried many variations on the code.
Thanks for your ideas.

MariaDB is a fork of MySQL. It is essentially the same product, and although there are now differences, they tend not to be at the schema level. Compare the MySQL schema with the schema in use with MariaDB. I'd expect there are some differences there.

Of you want to leave a numeric column empty, then pass null or perhaps 0 to it, not an empty string. Probably your mysql instance had strict sql mode disabled, which allowed your app to pass nonsensical values to the numeric columns.

your mysql instance didn't have sql_mode STRICT_TRANS_TABLES enabled.  disable it in your mariadb instance or be prepared to update a lot of your code.  there may be other sql_mode differences that cause other problems; you should generally try to make sql_mode changes intentionally, not as part of an upgrade.

Please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE and the value being inserted.  (Consider using print Date::Dumper($questionmarks);)

@RickJames likely the problem value is in @new_row

What in $placeholders, $question_marks, and @new_row? Are all of those what they should be?

Tip: You don't need use DBD::MariaDB;.

@Shadow where do I find this to modify it: 'strict sql mode disabled'

@ysth where do I modify this: 'didn't have sql_mode STRICT_TRANS_TABLES enabled'

do select @@sql_mode to see what it is set to. change it in the running server with set @@GLOBAL.sql_mode=replace(@@GLOBAL.sql_mode,'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES','');  then reconnect to the database to get the new setting.  set it in your mariadb configuration file sql_mode='...' in a [mariadb] section so the change lasts next time the server restarts

@dude di not disable strict sql mode, that's not the right answer here!

@ysth When using your code I get this error: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `set'

that was an sql statement, not a command line command.

@Shadow it is the right answer, for the moment.  yes, strict mode, only full group by, no zero dates, etc are very helpful and there is a reason they are defaults now, and ideally existing code should be adapted to work with them.  but when you've just had an inadvertent version change or switch from mysql to mariadb or vice versa is likely not the right time

You turn strict mode off and you will never know what issues need fixing. It is never convenient to fix problems that can be shoved under the rug.

The issue you're encountering is related to MariaDB and MySQL handless null and empty strings in columns that have not null. I would check that the columns in mytable  that are giving you trouble are correctly defined. In MariaDB, if you're trying to insert an empty string into it, you will be thrown an error, especially for integer columns.
You'll meed to adjust your Perl script to handle passing an empty string. You can either set the value to undef (which  in SQL corresponds to NULL) or ensure that the columns can accept empty strings.
use DBI;
use DBD::MariaDB;

my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:MariaDB:database=$database;host=localhost", $MYSQLuserid, $MYSQLpassword, { RaiseError => 1, PrintError => 0 });

# Ensure that any empty strings are converted to undef if the column should allow NULLs
my @new_row = map { $_ eq '' ? undef : $_ } @new_row;

my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO mytable ($placeholders) VALUES ($questionmarks)");
$sth->execute(@new_row) or die "Failed to execute statement: " . $sth->errstr;
$new_order_number = $sth->{mysql_insertid};  # Note: Use mysql_insertid to get the last insert id
$sth->finish() or die $DBI::errstr;
$dbh->disconnect() or die $DBI::errstr;

If a column should have a default value or accept NULL, make sure it's defined that way in the database schema. If the column is NOT NULL and there is no default, you must provide a value during the insert.

Thanks. What I thought but not what I wanted. Great answer.

What am I missing? Is there something you're looking for that isn't in the question?

I'm jsut guessing, but I think @dude meant they were hoping to not have to change the code any further.

I had just thought it to be easier to change the code.

Thanks @ivand. Sorry if I wasn't clear your answer is right. Just didn't want that much work. Thanks

ahh ok i see, hope your project goes well :)
